# Auto surround highlighted text

Tags: overleaf

I am using the Overleaf website as my LaTeX editor,

I do a lot of coding with r and have become custom to a feature within rstudio, this is where if you select a word, and then press the `{` key, it surrounds the thing you have highlighted with `{}`

For example,

Say I had

```
\sum\limits_s \in S
```

Then I could just highlight the `s \in S` part, and enter `{`, and it would surround it all, like so,

```
\sum\limits_{s \in S}
```

Is this possible on Overleaf/LaTeX?

If this is possible how can I extend this to other symbols, like `(` or `$`.

Comment: I'm on support staff at Overleaf - at the moment, this isn't something supported on our online editor, sorry about that. I'll register this as a suggestion for improvement, though! 

For now, it might help to use the Emacs or Vim keybinding options on Overleaf (you can select these in the main project menu) for better control over your input. There are also some locally installed text editors that support this, and you can use a local installation of TeX.

Comment: your wish is against the LaTeX syntax. it should not be supported since it will/can lead to errors in writing of documents.  strict using LaTeX syntax, you should write for example `\sum_{s}` or `\sum\limits_{s \in S}`

Comment: Could you expand on why it is against the syntax? I guess a better proposal is a, default off, option in settings etc.. @Zarko

Comment: @good199998, you should read some introductory text about LaTeX.  in them you will observe correct use of sub- and superscripts. I show you correct use of subscripts (and the same is valid for  superscripts).

Comment: @good199998 I've posted my comment as an answer - thanks for the edit to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm on support staff at Overleaf - at the moment, this isn't something supported on our online editor, sorry about that. I've registered this as a suggestion for improvement, though! For now, it might help to use the Emacs or Vim keybinding options on Overleaf (you can select these in the main project menu) for better control over your input. There are also some locally installed text editors that support this, and you can use a local installation of TeX.